# I would like to display my website inside an iframe but it does not appear

Tags: page, external, iframe

i'm trying to display my website inside an iframe for a marketing campaign. But when i try to display my website it's appear blank.

This is the code

Comment: The code is missing, please provide it.

Comment: You should post your code lines and which is your Magento version?